# How to compute the average of a string of floats

Tags: python-3.x

```
temp = "75.1,77.7,83.2,82.5,81.0,79.5,85.7"
```

I am stuck in this assignment and unable to find a relevant answer to help.

I’ve used `.split(",")` and `float()`
and I am still stuck here.

Comment: “I am still stuck.”   Please clarify *exactly* where you are stuck and what is not working as expected; by updating the question.

Comment: **Show us what you’ve done so far** so that we have something to start with. It’s much easier for us to help you with existing code, and people are far more likely to help when they don’t have to start from zero with "How do I do this?"

Answer (score 0):

```
temp = "75.1,77.7,83.2,82.5,81.0,79.5,85.7"

li = temp.split(",")

def avr(li):
    av = 0
    for i in li:
        av += float(i)
    return av/len(li)

print(avr(li))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sum()` to add the elements of a tuple of `float`s:

```py
temp = "75.1,77.7,83.2,82.5,81.0,79.5,85.7"

def average (s_vals):
    vals = tuple ( float(v) for v in s_vals.split(",") )
    return sum(vals) / len(vals)

print (average(temp))
```

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly similar to the answer by @emacsdrivesmenuts (GMTA).

However, opting to use the efficient `map` [function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) which should scale nicely for larger strings. This approach removes the `for` loop and explicit `float()` conversion of each value, and passes these operations to the lower-level (highly optimised) C implementation.

For example:

```
def mean(s):
    vals = tuple(map(float, s.split(',')))
    return sum(vals) / len(vals)
```

Example use:

```
temp = '75.1,77.7,83.2,82.5,81.0,79.5,85.7'

mean(temp)
>>> 80.67142857142858
```